# How can I mark all created emails through EWS as income mails and not drafts?

Tags: c#, email, exchangewebservices, managed

Just have a question about this problem, which i faced while using EWS and creating mails.

I´m creating and save the E-Mail to my Inbox.

```
            EmailMessage message = new EmailMessage(_exchangeService);
            message.From = emailObject.SenderAddress;
            message.Subject = emailObject.Subject;
            message.Body = emailObject.Body
            message.ToRecipients.Add(email);
            message.CcRecipients.Add(emailObject.CC);
            message.IsRead = false;
            message.Save(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox);
```

Now the problem is, that  EWS is creating the E-Mail as a draft.

Is it possible to mark the mail as an income mail?

Thank you!

Comment: this is impossible IMO. `IsDraft` message attribute is read only and managed by server. According to documentation "An item is a draft when it has not yet been sent.". Only solution for me here is to send message and delete it from `sent` folder after that

Comment: Ok, thank you anyway. I think, ill take this solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set PR_Message_Flags https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee160304(v=exchg.80).aspx property on the Message using an extended property which will then make the message appear as sent

```
ExtendedPropertyDefinition PR_MESSAGE_FLAGS = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(3591, MapiPropertyType.Integer);
message.SetExtendedProperty(PR_MESSAGE_FLAGS, 1);
```

Answer (score -2):

If I get you right you want to send it to yourselve?

```
System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
message.To.Add("recipient@bar.com");
message.Subject = "Important";
message.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("sender@bar.com");
message.Body = "Message";

System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("your.exchange.instance.url");
try
{
    smtp.Send(message);
}
catch (SmtpFailedRecipientException ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

Comment: This answer is not relevant. OP is using EWS, not SMTP.

Comment: Not relevant. I'm using EWS.